# How to send sms from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sms

I need to setup an application with the purpose of sending an sms . Already know the sms gateway type . But i really want to integrate with sim . i need to send via a sim ( which was connected to pc through COM port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Exampl1

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents serialport As New IO.Ports.SerialPort
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count - 1
            .Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If serialport.IsOpen Then
            serialport.Close()
        End If

        Try
            With serialport
                .PortName = ComboBox1.Text
                .BaudRate = 96000
                .Parity = Parity.None
                .DataBits = 8
                .StopBits = StopBits.One
                .Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
                .DtrEnable = True
                .RtsEnable = True
                .NewLine = vbCrLf
            End With
            serialport.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        serialport.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCr)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        serialport.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & "destination" & Chr(34) & vbCr)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        serialport.WriteLine("test message" & vbCrLf & Chr(26))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Class

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find free library that can help you with your task: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx?msg=3179142

Or you can opt some commercial library that do the same thing: http://www.logixmobile.com/products/mcorelib/index.asp, for instance.

Comment: Thanks apros . I am going with it